# How to setup SparkPost (E-mail API) with Freenom domain? How to setup MX DNS record?

Tags: rest, dns, email, sparkpost

I have read the Sparkpost documentation and have followed step by step... and waiting for my account to be verified ... Unfortunately, my account has been blocked without I know what is the reason ... Then I try to find the solution on the sparkpost website. ..Then I find this link that explains the reasons why the sparkpost account is blocked ... https://www.sparkpost.com/docs/getting-started/requirements-for-sending-domains/

3 Reasons:

1. You must own or have administrative access to your domain
2. An A record or MX record in DNS must exist for your domain
3. The organizational domain can not be used across more than one SparkPost account ..

Then I just know my DNS settings for my Freenom domain does not have MX type ... But I do not know how to get a free mail server ... I do not know how to setup MX in DNS settings ... I'm confused ... Can anyone tell me what should i do?

Note: I use 000webhost.com

[DNS Settings for my Freenom domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56CB6.jpg)

Comment: I've not used 000webhost before but a little Googling seems like it supports MX records. I will post links and what they say below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to here: [000webhost modify MX record](https://www.000webhost.com/website-faq/can-i-edit-mx-cname-a-records-of-my-domain-40) and [here](https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/adding-mx-record/66839/2)

This is what those links say:

> You can change the MX records your domain by navigating to cPanel and selecting 'Modify MX Record'. To have the ability to create or modify other DNS records such as CNAME or A record, you need to upgrade your account. Full DNS management is not included with free web hosting accounts.
>
> Panel > Set web address > your-domain > Manage > Modify MX records